# How to select a certain table cell in certain relation to another?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I have

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Infobox</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
        </tr>
        ⁞
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">[random stuff]</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- *** Where I want to add another row *** -->
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum ...</td>
        </tr>
        ⁞
```

What is the most elegant/efficient way to select and append my additional row? I've started with

```
$("table th:contains('Infobox')").closest('tbody th[colspan="2"]');
```

But that doesn't select what I want. Thanx for your help and merry X-mas :o)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gab0kLzs/?

Comment: The most elegant way is to use [Angular](https://angularjs.org/).

Comment: Thank you j08691, that's right what I was looking for. Great! Why don't you put it in an answer so that I can rate you gratefully and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

What about .after?

```
$("table th:contains('Infobox')").after("<tr></tr>")
```

This will append the HTML after the selector.

Comment: This is targeting the wrong element: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/y80gzL4k/1/ Please note where they want the new content inserted. e.g. `Where I want to add another row`

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is trying to use `closest` to search up and down the DOM. `closest` *only searches ancestors*.

It is a little vague how you wish to target the correct table, but following your example you will want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/y80gzL4k/2/

```
 $('table th:contains("Infobox")')
    .closest('tbody')
    .find('tr:has(th[colspan="2"]):last')
    .after("<tr><th>New row goes here</th></tr>");
```